# Regarding menus for authenticated users only

Tags: 7, users, routes

Using **Structures/Menus/User Menu** in DRUPAL 7 i am adding a custom menu link under it and providing a path to it as node/whatever_my_nid. It is working fine. I have cleared all cache. However this menu link is being displayed for all users. I want it to be displayed only for authenticated users and admin. This should be a simple thing to figure out but apparently i cannot. I thought it would have been a permission issues but i don't think so. Would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Edit: I found that this code may help:

```
<?php
global $user;
if ($user->uid) {
if ($menu = theme_menu_tree()) {
   $menu = "<div class=\"menu\">". $menu . "</div>";
   return $menu;
}
}
else {return;}
?>
```

But where do i place this code...In my page.tpl.php or somewhere else like in template.php in my themes?

I tried placing the above function in my theme's preprocess function as:

```
function ypwb_preprocess_block(&$variables, $hook) {
     if ($user->uid) {
        if ($menu = theme_menu_tree()) {
           $menu = "<div class=\"menu\">". $menu . "</div>";
           return $menu;
        }
      }
        else {return;}
    }
```

However, the menu is still showing for anonymous user as well.

Comment: "displayed only for authenticated and anonymous users". That's everyone.

Comment: @Letharion oh...my bad...i meant only authenticated and admi..have edited now

Comment: [Menu per role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) was written exactly for this usecase.

Comment: @Indrock yes but its still in dev version for Drupal7

Comment: @kewal I'm using the module on a site (in production) since 4 months and it just works fine for me. No issues :-)

Comment: @Indrock...ok i guess i will also go ahead with this...seems a lot easier than playing around with my tpl files

Comment: @kewal It is better to do that, rather then having to reinvent the wheel. Also, you can help the module to improve by submitting issues (if you come across any) in the issue queue; or by writing patches.

Comment: To me this looks more like an Access Control issue than showing/hiding menu based on roles. If you just hide the menu "block" from users, people can still access the node by simply typing the address node/x. However if you actually use Drupal's access control contributed modules and disable access for anonymous users to a certain page, then wherever the menu item for that node is, the link won't be displayed for anon users, and also can't be accessed by anon users even if they know the address. I guess what I'm trying to say is Protect the Nodes not the Block's visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do is:

1. Install and enable [Taxonomy Access](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access)
2. Create a vocabulary called **Access**
3. Create 2 terms in the new **Access** vocabulary: **Public** and **Private**
4. Attach the term reference fields for **Access** vocabulary to each node type you wish to protect. You may want to set the default value to "Public".
5. Go to Taxonomy Access configuration page and set **D** (deny) View access to Anonymous users on **Private** term. Leave the rest of the options (update delete view tag etc) **I** (ignore).
6. Configure the access control for Authenticated users and set **A** (allow) View access to Authenticated users on **Private** term, and set **I** (ignore) for all else.
7. Now all you need to do is set Private on nodes you wish to protect, and set Public for all else.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Indrock, i got a very simple and effective answer
[Menu per role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) is the way to do so.

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items based on user roles. It depends on the Drupal core menu.module—just activate both modules and edit a menu item as usual. There will be a new fieldset that allows you to restrict access by role. The fieldset also appears in the node edit form.

Comment: If you have XML sitemap on your website you're not really protecting that node, people can still access it from a search engine/copying the link from your sitemap. It's not really an effective solution imho.

Comment: hmm...that is a point to be considered....so what do you suggest

Comment: I suggest using one of the Access Control modules like [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) or [Taxonomy Access](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) or there's a whole list of them including the above 2 I mentioned on the [Menu Per Role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module's page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting it in a block, then create 2 menus.

Then create 2 menu blocks, linking to these 2 menus.

Restrict the 'logged in' version to authenticated roles and the anonymous user menu block to  the *anonymous user* role.